# Putting a txt lines into diffrent arrays or arraylists

Tags: java

I just wanted to ask, let say we have 10 lines in a txt file and each include diffrent kind of numbers. And I want to put the numbers in each line on a different arraylists. what can I do for it?
Here is the example:

31 44 43 43 43 43 43 45 45 45 44 45 45 45 46 46 45 45 46 46 46 45 45 45 45 45 44 45 45 45 45 46 29 47 46 48 49 48 49 49 49 48 49 49 50 48 48 48 49 49 49 49 50 50 50 50 50 50 49 51 51 51 
31 49 50 48 49 50 51 51 52 52 52 52 51 52 52 52 52 53 53 54 54 54 54 54 54 53 53 53 54 55 55 54 30 54 54 56 56 56 56 56 56 57 57 57 57 57 57 58 58 56 57 57 58 58 58 58 58 59 60 60 60 61 62 
31 60 59 61 61 62 62 63 62 62 62 64 64 64 64 64 66 65 66 65 65 65 65 66 67 67 66 66 67 66 66 67 30 68 69 68 68 69 67 67 68 69 68 68 68 69 69 69 69 71 71 71 70 71 70 70 70 72 71 71 71 71 72 
31 70 72 73 73 72 73 74 74 74 73 75 76 75 75 75 75 76 77 76 76 77 76 76 76 77 77 78 77 77 77 77 31 75 75 76 76 75 76 77 78 79 77 77 77 75 75 74 73 76 75 74 75 74 74 73 73 73 73 72 74 74 72 72 30 72 73 73 73 72 72 71 71 71 71 70 71 72 71 68 68 68 68 67 68 69 69 68 67 67 66 67 66 66 66 
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

```
    List<int[]> arrays = new ArrayList<int[]>();

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("weather.txt"));

    for (String line = reader.readLine(); line != null; line = reader.readLine()) {
        String[] intStrings = line.split(" ");
        int[] ints = new int[intStrings.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < ints.length; ++i) {
            ints[i] = Integer.parseInt(intStrings[i]);
        }
        arrays.add(ints);
    }`enter code here`
    for (int[] name : arrays) {
        System.out.println(name);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! what you have tried by yourself?

Comment: @Sheri I tried that

Comment: Paste your code in your question not in comments

Comment: bu the thing is it is not outputting correctly                                                                                             [I@65b54208
[I@1be6f5c3
[I@6b884d57
[I@38af3868
[I@77459877
[I@5b2133b1                                                                                         THis is the output

Comment: That's just what happens when you print an array. Use `Arrays.toString` to format it correctly: `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(name));`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the simplest way to print a Java array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/409784/whats-the-simplest-way-to-print-a-java-array)

Comment: @Schred I tried it but this is an arraylist. it doesnt work.

Comment: You're not supposed to do that with `arrays`. Put that in your loop after `'enter code here'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not how you print arrays in java.

Instead of this loop:

```
for (int[] name : arrays) {
    System.out.println(name);
}
```

Do this:

```
for (int[] name : arrays) {
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(name));
}
```

Or you could skip the loop entirely:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(arrays.toArray()));
```

Comment: thank you  really much, it is done!!!

Comment: You're welcome. ;D